# How to make a DC sweep with negative change in pspice orcad?

Tags: simulation, pspice, orcad

I have the following circuit and I want to varry V1 from 24V to 0v while keeping V2 = 5V, naturally I tried using DC sweep simulation with start value of 24V, end value of 0V and variation of -1, but that gave a variation from 0V to 24V, I've tried changing the variation to 1, that gave the same results.

So my question is : how can I make DC sweep simulation with negative variation?
I am using pspice with orcad 16.4

[image]

Comment: How can you tell which order the sweep was done? If you're just looking at a graph, of course 0 V is still on the left of the x-axis and 24 V is on the right, even if the sweep was done the other way.

Comment: @ThePhoton I deduced from the current curve, since I'm using a thyristor it should switch to off once the current goes below the holding current (At 24v it's already turned on)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be OP's exact requirement, however, it will work just as fine: instead of a `DC` sweep use a `TRAN` analysis, with `V1` set as a decreasing ramp, e.g. `PWL 0 24 1 0`. `PULSE()` will work, too. Then simply replace `time` with another quantity after the simulation has run, e.g. `I(V2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try varying voltage V1 in Eg: -10 to 24 with the increment of 1. Since there is a increment it should always be increasing. This will increment form -10 in step of 1 till 24.
[image: Simulation Settings]

Comment: OP wants *decreasing*, not increasing. The increment must be negative, and then the simulator needs to correctly interpret that and allow a decreasing sweep.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I will delete the answer since it misguides/ makes no sense.

Comment: First try to see if it actually works with negative increment. If it does, then it's an answer like any others.